# How do I block a user/cancel a user account in Simpletest?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to write some tests for a module for situations in which a user is blocked.  I know I can use `drupalCreateUser()` to make new users, but how do I block a user I have created in Simpletest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the user object back from `drupalCreateUser()` you can use standard API methods to make changes (in this case [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7)):

```
user_save($user, array('status' => 0));
```